# AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'parallel_interleave'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I encounter this error while trying to use apply method on tensorflow 2 Dataset, here is the code I wrote:

```
from tensorflow import data as tfdata

dataset = tfdata.Dataset.list_files(
    self._file_pattern,
    shuffle=self._is_training,
    seed=tf.random.set_random_seed(int(time.time() * 1e9)))
if self._is_training:
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

Then apply method:

```
# Prefetch data from files.
def _prefetch_dataset(filename):
  dataset = tfdata.TFRecordDataset(
      filename, buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE).prefetch(1)
  return dataset

dataset = dataset.apply(
    tfdata.Dataset.parallel_interleave(
    _prefetch_dataset, cycle_length=32, sloppy=self._is_training))
```

Comment: update your tensorflow and t2t as stated in : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/issues/558

Comment: i'm using tf 2.1 and contrib module is no longer supported. The solution use gave is used for tf 1.x only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.x we don't need to use `apply` method any more. Simply use `dataset = dataset.interleave()` instead of `dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave`())